# sum a column in a sharepoint 2007 list and pass the resault to another list

Tags: xpath, sharepoint-2007, xls

I am very new in share point. I have 2 lists, projects and tasks as follow:

```
Projects List
-------------------------------------
project title | %Complete |
PJ 01              0%
PJ 02              0%

Tasks List
-------------------------------------
Task title    | Project title  |  %Complete  |
T01                PJ01              10%
T02                PJ01              15%
T03                PJ02               0%
T04                PJ02              20%
```

i want to sum %complete Column of tasks list based on project title and update the corresponding rows in Projects Lists.

```
Projects List
-------------------------------------
project title | %Complete |
PJ 01              25%
PJ 02              20%
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a workflow in SharePoint Designer would be a good solution for this.  The workflow could fire anytime an item in the task list is edited or created.  The workflow will add the percent complete for items with that same project title into a workflow variable.  Then it will update the Project in the project list with the value in that variable.

On second thought, this is touching on some rather advanced SharePoint implementation since it's not out of the box functionality.

Since there is no way to do this out of the box, you should look into a 3rd party solution. Here's one which we have used: https://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=AssociatedTasks

This allows you to use summary columns to automatically generate summary values of your related items (e.g count, sum, average, concatenate).

Comment: thanx a lot Cam, but as i mentioned before i am new to share point. is it possible for you to provide a step by step procedure with this?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the answer.